# Log4net log file stop rolling after logstash implementation (Windows)

Tags: log4net, logstash

Before I implemented Logstash into my system, my log4net file will roll to a new log file when it hits 4MB. But the behavior right now is it will not roll to a new log file, instead it removes the content within the log file and append the new log message to the same log file. It seems like Logstash is locking the log4net log file and preventing it from rolling it over.

Did i do something wrong here? Or this is a bug for logstash within windows?

FYI, The version of logstash i used was v1.4.2.

Below are the codes for logstash file input :

```
input { 
    file {
        path => "C:/Logs/*"
        exclude => "*.ERROR.log"
        codec => multiline {
                    pattern => "^(WARN|ERROR|INFO)"
                    negate => true
                    what => previous
                }
      }
}
```

Below are the code for log4net configuration for my console app:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %a %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M [%t] - %m MsgEnd%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %a %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M [%t] - %m MsgEnd%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:Logs\\APICentral.ProcessRunner.ALL.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
      <maximumFileSize value="4MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %a %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M [%t] - %m MsgEnd%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ErrorOnlyRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\Logs\\APICentral.ProcessRunner.ERROR.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %a %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M [%t] - %m MsgEnd%n" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="WARN" />
        <levelMax value="ERROR" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorOnlyRollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Not sure about log4net specifically, but this has been a problem on Windows for a while now.. https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-986 . pretty much makes it unusable for us too.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Our logs stop rolling by date when Logstash service is running...

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1557, this has been fixed in Logstash version 1.5